# SSH key verification fails when connecting for first time

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm trying to connect and it fails to verify key. I have no problems when connecting by PuTTY.

```
$ ssh -v xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/atlavis/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/atlavis/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/atlavis/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/atlavis/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/atlavis/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/atlavis/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1
Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 23:d4:48:da:99:bf:f5:c0:5f:4b:a9:6f:06:0f:76:9a
The authenticity of host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 23:d4:48:da:99:bf:f5:c0:5f:4b:a9:6f:06:0f:76:9a.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Host key verification failed.
```

What's going on there?

edit.

Contents of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Comment: Does your account have the ability to write changes to the known_hosts file?  Check the ownership and permissions.

Comment: Yes, it does. `/home/atlavis/.ssh/known_hosts` is empty actually.

Comment: I don't know what is going on but you might find some answers googling "Host key verification failed"  http://askubuntu.com/questions/45679/ssh-connection-problem-with-host-key-verification-failed-error    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018385/host-key-verification-failed

Comment: These answers are related to when host key changed. I connect for first time to remote host, so that's another situation.